# Is there an equivalent to WLAN_FRAME_STATISTICS on MacOS?

Tags: objective-c, windows, macos

On Windows, the `WlanQueryInterface` function allows to retrieve a `WLAN_STATISTICS` struct, which in turn contains `WLAN_PHY_FRAME_STATISTICS` with a bunch of useful counters about sent and received PHY frames.

Now, I'm looking for a similar possibility under MacOS. I've checked `CoreWLAN`, but it only contains `CWInterface`'s information, but this doesn't have any frame statistics (i.e. number of frames sent on first attempt, number of frames that needed retransmission, etc.). Is there any other possibility to retrieve this information on MacOS? Maybe with `sysctl`, or via a third-party library?